# Adding new dataFrame column to the same dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

Issue: Getting the SettingWithCopy warning.

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
>   using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Goal: 
Separate the column data into separate columns, all in the same DataFrame.

Input: 
A Dataframe with 2 columns. First column is an email address and the second contains a list of dates separated by semicolons.

Code:

```
for dt in lunch_dates:
    roulette_data[dt] = roulette_data['date'].str.contains(dt).map(bool_conversion)
```

What I want this code to do (and it does): 
Add a new column for each date found (dt) in the originating date column.

Question: How to use iloc in this case, to ensure I am not working on a possible copy of the dataframe in memory?

Comment: could you share some of your data and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your example

Without data to test it on, I cannot test it but the below should work (replace your 'email_column_name' with the name of the email column):

```
dates = pd.get_dummies(
                       roulette_data.set_index('email_column_name')['date']\
                       .str.split(';',expand=True)\
                       .stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                      )\
                      .reset_index().groupby('email_column_name').sum()
```

## Here is a toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['record1', 'record2'], 
                  'col2':["this is good text", "but this is even better"]}
                 )

df
#      col1                     col2
#0  record1        this is good text
#1  record2  but this is even better
```

We first set the index to be `col1`, then we select `col2`, so we can use its `.str.split` method to split the lines into individual words.

```
df.set_index('col1')['col2'].str.split(expand=True)
#            0     1     2     3       4
#col1                                   
#record1  this    is  good  text    None
#record2   but  this    is  even  better
```

Then we use `stack` to change the shape and `reset_index` to get rid of the unnecessary index level

```
df.set_index('col1')['col2'].str.split(expand=True)\
            .stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True) 
#col1
#record1      this
#record1        is
#record1      good
#record1      text
#record2       but
#record2      this
#record2        is
#record2      even
#record2    better
#dtype: object
```

We wrap this whole expression in pd.get_dummies()

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('col1')['col2'].str.split(expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

#         better  but  even  good  is  text  this
#col1                                            
#record1       0    0     0     0   0     0     1
#record1       0    0     0     0   1     0     0
#record1       0    0     0     1   0     0     0
#record1       0    0     0     0   0     1     0
#record2       0    1     0     0   0     0     0
#record2       0    0     0     0   0     0     1
#record2       0    0     0     0   1     0     0
#record2       0    0     1     0   0     0     0
#record2       1    0     0     0   0     0     0
```

#### End result

Finally we `reset_index` (which is `col1` or in your case the e-mail column), `groupby` the `col1` and sum over it.

```
pd.get_dummies(
               df.set_index('col1')['col2']\
               .str.split(expand=True)\
               .stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
              )\
              .reset_index().groupby('col1').sum()
#         better  but  even  good  is  text  this
#col1                                            
#record1       0    0     0     1   1     1     1
#record2       1    1     1     0   1     0     1
```